# Replicating Lightroom's "Aged Photo" Preset in Photoshop

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, presets

I was messing around with a post-processed imaged and found that the Aged Photo preset in Lightroom did something fantastic to one part of my image.  But I don't care for the sepia-like coloring and I also want to restrict the effect to that one portion of the image.

How can I replicate this effect using adjustment layers in Photoshop?  I can tell there's some vignetting.  I think it might be brightening the highlights.  But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: If you could post a before and after that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightroom presets are no magic, they just change development settings. Aged Photo is really simple, some playing around with brightness, contrast, saturation and noise reduction. Switch to development mode and apply-undo the preset a few times, observing development settings. Should be really clear what it does. Also, see [Is there a way to decompose a Lightroom preset?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5165/is-there-a-way-to-decompose-a-lightroom-preset)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That was the information I was looking for: